# what's the function of tag '#' while using python string format option

Tags: python, string, formatter

I am using python string format option, and after reading [document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting), i am still confused by '#' cause i really don't know the meaning of this phrase '*The value conversion will use the “alternate form” (where defined below).*'. Great thanks to someone that helps me.

Here is some test:

```
print '%#sabc' % 'ABC'
```

> 'ABCabc'

```
print '%#fabc' % 1.2
```

> 1.200000abc

That will be great if there are some examples of usage of '#' here.

Comment: What the alternate form is is explained a few lines later, in the first notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "alternative form" changes the behavior of the selected conversion slightly.

### Your Example for floating point representation:

> 'f': Floating point decimal format.

```
>>> print("%.0f" % 1)
1
```

> The alternate form causes the result to always contain a decimal point, even if no digits follow it.

```
>>> print("%#.0f" % 1)
1.
```

### Example for hexadecimal representation:

> 'x': Signed hexadecimal (lowercase).

```
>>> print("%x" % -11)
-b
```

> The alternate form causes a leading '0x' [...] to be inserted before the first digit.

```
>>> print("%#x" % -11)
-0xb
```

Comment: @chenkh Please mark as 'answered' if it answered your question.  I don't think you'll find a better answer!

Answer (score 1):

As per the notes on that document, an 'alternate form' is defined for some conversion types.

e.g. in your example with `%#f`

> 3.The alternate form causes the result to always contain a decimal point, even if no digits follow it.

There is no defined 'Alternate form' for strings so `%s` and `%#s` are equivalent

Comment: how can i see the difference between '%f' and '%#f', could you please show me an example? understanding notes is difficult for me.

Comment: Try printing both and see what happens!  See the examples in Christian's answer